# What's default image quality in toDataURL?

Tags: html, todataurl

Here is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) for `toDataURL`:

```
Syntax

canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);

Parameters

type Optional
    A DOMString indicating the image format. The default type is image/png.

encoderOptions Optional
    A Number between 0 and 1 indicating image quality if the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp.
    If this argument is anything else, the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.
```

`If this argument is anything else, the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.`. What's the default value for image quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Blink: 0.92 for JPEG and 0.80 for WEBP.

## Gecko: 0.92 for JPEG (no webp support)

### How I found it

I searched for "toDataURL" using https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch

Relevant code
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/HTMLCanvasElement.cpp&q=toDataURL&sq=package:chromium&l=517

Looks like it sets the quality like so `double quality = UndefinedQualityValue;` where `UndefinedQualityValue;` is a constant of -1.0.

Following the call chain further down we get to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/graphics/ImageBuffer.cpp&sq=package:chromium&l=348&rcl=1448382621

```
bool ImageDataBuffer::encodeImage(const String& mimeType, const double& quality, Vector<unsigned char>* encodedImage) const
{
    if (mimeType == "image/jpeg") {
        int compressionQuality = JPEGImageEncoder::DefaultCompressionQuality;
        if (quality >= 0.0 && quality <= 1.0)
            compressionQuality = static_cast<int>(quality * 100 + 0.5);
        if (!JPEGImageEncoder::encode(*this, compressionQuality, encodedImage))
            return false;
    } else if (mimeType == "image/webp") {
        int compressionQuality = WEBPImageEncoder::DefaultCompressionQuality;
        if (quality >= 0.0 && quality <= 1.0)
            compressionQuality = static_cast<int>(quality * 100 + 0.5);
        if (!WEBPImageEncoder::encode(*this, compressionQuality, encodedImage))
            return false;
    } else {
        if (!PNGImageEncoder::encode(*this, encodedImage))
            return false;
        ASSERT(mimeType == "image/png");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Where the values are as follows:

- `JPEGImageEncoder::DefaultCompressionQuality = 92` [source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/image-encoders/skia/JPEGImageEncoder.h&sq=package:chromium&l=46&rcl=1448382621)
- `WEBPImageEncoder::DefaultCompressionQuality = 80` [source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/image-encoders/skia/WEBPImageEncoder.h&sq=package:chromium&l=46&rcl=1448382621)

### Gecko

We can follow a similar process as the above with mozilla code search, or just google "gecko image encoder" which takes you to the following value:
JPEG: 0.92 [source](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/image/encoders/jpeg/nsJPEGEncoder.cpp#L89)