# Canvas doesn't draw edge correctly when extract image from sprite image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried to use *ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);* API to extract image from a sprite image. But I found Canvas renders the edge from the adjacent images which I don't want.

For example:

First, I use a 800x400 canvas to draw 400x400 red rect, and draw 400x200 green rect after the red rect, then save the data to JPG file.

[image]

Then I want to extract green rect to draw onto another canvas, so I use syntax like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(this, 400, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, 400, 400);
```

In theory, there is only the color data from the green rect on the canvas, but there is red color on left edge.

[JSBIN SAMPLE LINK](http://jsbin.com/figuyoyebo/edit?html,js,output)

Does anyone know the reason why cause this problem? Do I misunderstand the API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont know the api Have, but you tried starting at 1 instead of 0 when using drawImage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of jpeg compression.
You probably did set the quality parameter of `toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality)` to something else than the maximum <s>and default</s> `1` *[edit: actually, as found out by OP, the default is `.92`]*.
By doing so, the jpeg algorithm will take bigger blocks of pixels to do its lossy compression. You can see that on your image, where the two rects do collide, there is some antialiasing artifacts.

The lower the compression, the bigger these artifacts will be :

```js
// your original canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var _ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 400;
_ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
_ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
_ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
_ctx.fillRect(400, 100, 400, 200);


var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
  // lets zoom a little bit
  ctx.drawImage(this, 300, 0, 300, 300, 0, 0, 400, 400);
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('output').getContext('2d');

// since we do zoom the image, lets try to keep antialiasing as its minimum
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

range.oninput = function() {
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', +this.value);
}
range.oninput();
```

```html
<label>JPEG quality: <input type="range" id="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1"></label><br>
<canvas id="output" height="400"></canvas>
```

JPEG is great for pictures, but with such images, you should stick to png, which will offer an lossless compression, and will even produce an smaller image size on this exact image :

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var _ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 400;
_ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
_ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
_ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
_ctx.fillRect(400, 100, 400, 200);


var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
  // lets zoom even more
  ctx.drawImage(this, 300, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, 400, 400);
}
var ctx = document.getElementById('output').getContext('2d');
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled =
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

canvas.toBlob(function(b){console.log('jpg_size', b.size)}, 'image/jpeg', .1);
canvas.toBlob(function(b){console.log('png_size', b.size)}, 'image/png');
```

```html
<canvas id="output" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I appreciate it!

Comment: By the way, I just checked the default quality parameter of toDataURL, I found an article said that the default value is 0.92.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904144/whats-default-image-quality-in-todataurl

Comment: @Sam, you're completely right, I forgot about it, shame on me... Did update.