# canvas ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight) not pixel perfect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried to use ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight) to cut a tileset. But when my tile is drawn with width and height higher that original size, we can see some pixels of others tiles (left, top, right and bottom).

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298089/canvas-doesnt-draw-edge-correctly-when-extract-image-from-sprite-image) and tried to change from PNG to JPG without compression but still have the bad borders...

Here is my tileset (zoomed to see pixels) :

[image]

Black is 1px separator between my tiles, so my tiles are red-yellow-green-blue 16x16px squares.
If I draw the first square with `ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, 0, 0, 16, 16);` everything is ok. BUT, if I draw a higher square like this : `ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, 0, 0, 64, 64);` there is black lines around my tile.

Please check this code :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    let tileSize = 16;
    let offset = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, x*tileSize+offset, y*tileSize+offset, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
    tileSize = 64;
    offset = 100;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, x*tileSize+offset, y*tileSize+offset, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  };
  //img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/hrHOjWc.png';
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/sW6m5kr.jpg';
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="900" width="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: Possibly because `50` is not evenly divisible by `16` so when you scale, some rounding has to be done.

Comment: In my code snippet I used 64 instead of 50. Same black lines

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found, with `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` it seems to fix my issue :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; // <== FIX

function draw() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    let tileSize = 16;
    let offset = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, x*tileSize+offset, y*tileSize+offset, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
    tileSize = 64;
    offset = 100;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 16, 16, x*tileSize+offset, y*tileSize+offset, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  };
  //img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/hrHOjWc.png';
  img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/sW6m5kr.jpg';
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="900" width="900"></canvas>
```